# ipython weird behaviour with sequence unpacking

Tags: python, ipython

I have a weird behavior with sequence unpacking in ipython

```
In [12]: items = [1, 10, 7, 4, 5, 9]

In [13]: head, *tail = items
  File "<ipython-input-13-34256df22cca>", line 1
    head, *tail = items
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax ([PEP 3132 - Extended Iterable Unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)) was introduced in Python 3.0. Check you python version.

In Python 3.3:

```
>>> items = [1, 10, 7, 4, 5, 9]
>>> head, *tail = items
>>> head
1
>>> tail
[10, 7, 4, 5, 9]
```

In Python 2.7, it raises SyntaxError:

```
>>> items = [1, 10, 7, 4, 5, 9]
>>> head, *tail = items
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    head, *tail = items
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> head, tail = items[0], items[1:] # workaround
>>> head
1
>>> tail
[10, 7, 4, 5, 9]
```

Comment: So unpacking iterables using * syntax is not available in Python 2.7 is that what you mean here ?

Comment: Thanks any idea how i do this in Python 2.7

Comment: @jhon.smith, Try `head, tail = items[0], items[1:]`.

Comment: @jhon.smith this *specific* syntax for unpacking as a "catch-all" is not available in 2.x.  Unpacking into function arguments works normally.